# How to use Continuous Speech to Text In IONIC

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I have successfully integrated [Speech Recognition](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition/) API in my project(IONIC 3). But to input voice i need to call this.speechRecognition.startListening every time.

Is there any way i can continuously run this as a server? So that at any point if someone says something it will converted to text.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: @JohnAndrews we didn't continue working on that. We couldn't find anything good regarding that.

Comment: Such a waste framework Ionic. My 10 days went in vain

Comment: Call it in a loop?

Comment: Did any body found something yet?

Comment: I already search but not found anything helpful maybe continues listening is not a option or other way does continues listening will harm customer privacy, The plugin will record what customer saying all time.

Answer (score 0):

I came with my solution there is no way to use continue listening officially by plugin.
But we can use **Recursion** concept for make that happen.

```
 this.speechRecognition.startListening(option).subscribe((matches: Array<string>) => { 
    this.voiceArray = matches; 
    // Now we get what user said so we can call again for active start listening. 
    this.start();
  }, (onerror) => {
       console.log('Error::::', onerror);
       // Error occure when user does not say anything in that case we can call again.
       this.start();
   }
```

Note: put all listening code inside start() function and call it. but you have to deal with that annoying beep sound continuously. for that you can use cordova audioManagment plugin(This will silent user device not a good for all time).

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Rajat.r2 is not perfect, it consumes a lot of power according to: [apple doc on Speech Recognition (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognizer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uaVV.png)

I guess that the best way would be to use a wake word service like: https://picovoice.ai/docs/porcupine/ and then process the rest of your stuff with native Speech recognition. The  issue is that it's a paid service. I will try that right know for one of my app.